# In JavaScript ES6, how are names isolated in each file, when JavaScript files are often concatenated into a single file?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

In ES6, if there is some code in a file:

```
const foo = 1;
var bar = { a: 3.14 };
export const wah = 1.414;
```

then `foo`, `bar`, and `wah` are isolated (silo'ed) within this file, unless if other files do an

```
import { wah } from "some-file";
```

`foo` and `bar` remain isolated and there is no way for other files to import or know about them.

But since often, JavaScript files are concatenated into one single file, then how can one file isolate the names from other files when everything is in one file?

Comment: Webpack uses closures to "isolate" variables, objects, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You don't simply `concatenate` the files into one single files. The 'bundling' software, like webpack or browserify will wrap these modules ('single files') with closures, therefore variables and methods will be local to these modules.

You don't need to use ES6 to see how it works. In 'olden days' you could also run scripts to concatenate js files. Depending on how your files were structured the variables could have been 'local' or global.

```
// file one.js
(function() {
    var localVariable = 'I am local';
})();

//file two.js
var notSoLocal = 'I am NOT local';
```

Comment: if it is using local scopes to isolate the names in the local scope, then how does it handle export and import?

Comment: The same way modules handle it.

Answer (score 2):

> But since often, JavaScript files are concatenated into one single file, then how can one file isolate the names from other files when everything is in one file?

By not simply concatenating everything into a single file if you are using ES6 modules.

Use an ES6 aware tool like webpack instead.

Comment: so for React apps, everything will be in `bundle.js`... what's the difference between that and having everything concatenated into one file that makes the names isolated within each file?